# Can Riak be used with a third party key value store as the backend

Tags: backend, riak, key-value-store

Can Riak be configured to use a third party backend? In a prior question a Basho employee said that you could "edit the config file and restart the server". What else would you need to do to connect a backend vey value store such as rocksDB (built as a shared library in a linux .so file) modified to provide the same API as Bitcask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you certainly could, LevelDB is also built as a .so file. However, LeveDB's API differs from how Riak expects a backend to behave, so it requires and interface module [riak_kv_eleveldb_backend](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/develop/src/riak_kv_eleveldb_backend.erl) so that it responds to Riak the way it expects.  You would likely need to do the same for any other third party backend.

Comment: Thank you for the link. for my purposes my experimental backend can pretend to be LevelDB & use this interface module. I would up vote the answer but I have insufficient cred...